# How to run multiple express/Nodejs application in localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am running my client(frondend) app express app in a port 3000 and another admin express app in 8080.

But when I am navigating any pages  or refreshing any page in client express app, the session in admin app is lost and redirecting to login.

I am using Express-session npm for admin and frond end is just like a cms frondend, ie no sessions or anything complex. Can any body tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Without knowing how you setup the session handling in your code it is not possible to tell. But I would doubt that the session is _lost_ because of navigating in the other node app.  It is more likely that you set a low lifetime for the session and that it just times out because of inactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies for an app running on port 3000 are also sent to an app running on port 8080 (and vice versa).

My guess is that you didn't give each app a unique [cookie name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#name), so you might get interference between the session handling of both apps.

So, use a different cookie name for each:

```
app.use(session({
  name : 'frontend.sid', // and, say, 'admin.sid' for the admin app
  ...
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Robert.. This works... And May I ask you one more which I found session-memory-store module. SInce express-session stores value on memory store, using this for production wont be viable (as said in doc itself not suit for production). So Using session-memory-store do provide any help in production??

Comment: @AkhilGopan I wouldn't use the memory store in production. But [there are a lot of alternatives](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores), perhaps one that will work with a database that you're already using.

Comment: Thankyou Robert...I use Postgres and I will implement using it.

Answer (score 0):

***Run in different browsers*** :

try one of them in different browser like one in `chrome` and other in `mozilla`. It is happening due to session clashing over there.

> Changing the browser might be a good solution for you.

***Want to run in same browser*** :

Just run one service in `normal mode` and run other service in `incognito mode`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information I would suggest that you look over to the way you are initialising express-session. In case that the `secure` flag is set to true, it would expect a valid HTTPS certificate to be set for localhost, otherwise the session wont be created which can cause redirect problems.

From the docs:

> secure: Specifies the boolean value for the Secure Set-Cookie
>   attribute. When truthy, the Secure attribute is set, otherwise it is
>   not. By default, the Secure attribute is not set.
>   Please note that secure: true is a recommended option. However, it
>   requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure
>   cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the
>   cookie will not be set.